# AJAX передает искаженные данные с сервера

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, wordpress

Есть файл time.php

```
<?php       
         function clock(){          
              $now = time();            
              $H = date('H', $now);             
              $i= date('i', $now);          
              $vremya = "Current time:  "."$H:$i";      
        return $vremya;         
        }           
      echo $a = clock();
?>
```

в шаблон его вставляет файл time.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post('/time.php', onAjaxSuccess);

    function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
        // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим их на экран.
        $("#time").html(data);
    }
});
```

Но в шаблоне показано искаженное время сервера (-5 часов)0_о, если вставить php-скрипт напрямую в шаблон, то время сервера выводится корректно! В чем тут проблема?

Comment: Проверил ваш код и на локальном сервере и в инете - проблем не возникло, но пробовал без CMS. Остается одно - проблема явно в настройках WordPress. Проверьте "Часовой пояс" в "Настройках" > "Общие"

Comment: А не проще выводить время через JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию [WP считает время в UTC](http://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/general-settings/#timezone). Либо измените настройку в WP, либо костыль: вручную сбрасывайте временную зону на вашу, и потом восстанавливайте исходное значение, примерно так:

```
<?php       
     function clock() {
        $backup_tz = date_default_timezone_get(); // на память
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Yekaterinburg'); // ваш пояс
        $now = time();            
        $H = date('H', $now);             
        $i= date('i', $now);          
        $vremya = "Current time:  "."$H:$i";      
        date_default_timezone_set($backup_tz); // время назад
        return $vremya;         
    }           
    echo $a = clock();
?>
```